# Calling pyplot.bar, not getting a chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I execute this code it doesn't produce a chart. I can't see why.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = 75
c = 0
m = 2**(31) -1
x = 0.1
u=np.array([])
for i in range(0,100):
    x= np.mod((a*x+c),m)
    u= np.append(u,x/m)
    print(u[i])
N=100
s=20
Ns =N/s
S = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
counts = np.empty(S.shape, dtype=int)
V=0
for i in range(0,20):
    counts[i] = len(np.where((u >= S[i]) & (u < S[i]+0.05))[0])
    V=V+(counts[i]-Ns)**2 / Ns
print("R = ",counts)
print("V = ", V)
Ypos = np.arange(len(counts))
plt.bar(Ypos,counts)
print(plt)
```

Comment: What is `print(plt)` supposed to do? You are missing the `plt.show()` call in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = 75
c = 0
m = 2**(31) -1
x = 0.1
u=np.array([])
for i in range(0,100):
    x= np.mod((a*x+c),m)
    u= np.append(u,x/m)
    print(u[i])
N=100
s=20
Ns =N/s
S = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
counts = np.empty(S.shape, dtype=int)
V=0
for i in range(0,20):
    counts[i] = len(np.where((u >= S[i]) & (u < S[i]+0.05))[0])
    V=V+(counts[i]-Ns)**2 / Ns
print("R = ",counts)
print("V = ", V)
Ypos = np.arange(len(counts))
plt.bar(Ypos,counts)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, I omitted the call to show() :)